# Hourly Aggregation at each timestamp in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I  have simple graph having 5 nodes A,B,C,D,E in following way

[image]

I have time series data for nodes B,C,D,E in following way :

```
DateTime,Value,NodeName
2016-01-01 00:00:00,1.2,B
2016-01-01 00:15:00,1.3,B
------
------
2016-12-31 11:30:00,1.2,B
2016-12-31 11:45:00,1.3,B
2016-01-01 00:00:00,1.28,C
2016-01-01 00:15:00,1.3,C
------
------
2016-12-31 11:30:00,1.28,E
2016-12-31 11:45:00,1.3,E
```

I have to find `hourly aggregation` at node A for each timestamp present in above time-series data for whole year. I am able to implement the same for single timestamp through simple `sum` function but kind of clueless of efficient way for aggregation at all timestamps. Kindly help for the same

**UPDATE**

```
val df_v_3_h = df_v_2
.groupBy($"NodeName",
window(col("DateTime"), "1 hour", "1 hour", "30 minutes"))
.agg(sum("Value") as "aggregate_sum")
.select("window.start", "window.end", "aggregate_sum", "LoadProfile")
.sort("NodeName", "start")
df_v_3_h.createOrReplaceTempView("timestamps")

val df_v_4_h = df_v_3_h.sqlContext.sql(
"SELECT aggregate_sum,NodeName FROM timestamps WHERE 
start=CAST('2017-01-01 10:00:00.000' AS TIMESTAMP)")

    val df_v_5 = df_v_4_graph
.join(df_v_4_h, $"NodeName" === $"Connected Node Name", "inner")
          .select(col("RootNodeName"), col("aggregate_sum"))
          .groupBy(col("RootNodeName"))
          .agg(sum(col("aggregate_sum")))
```

df_v_4_graph is a dataset of following values :

```
RootNodeName,Connected Node Name
A,B
A,C
A,C
A,D

RootNodeName,Connected Node Name
A,B
A,C
A,E
A,D
A,B
```

Comment: Can you add the code you use for a single timestamp? Then it would be easier to know what you expect as output.

Comment: What's _"to find aggregation at node A"_? What's a _"graph"_? And what's _"each graph at each timestamp over whole year time series"_? Is the notion of "graph" used for the problem? (that leads me to think in graph way with all the graph algorithms and am afraid I'm getting more clueless).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I have updated code and language too.Sorry for making you clueless.

Comment: @Shaido ,I have provided the code.